# Define Log file in Logback

Tags: slf4j, logback

I want to set a log file and log directory, so that all the logging of my program will be saved there.
I am planning to use logback, with SLF4J API.

how and where I should make the necessary definitions?

Comment: This isn't really a question about a specific problem. If you are just starting out, I suggest consulting the logback manual: http://logback.qos.ch/manual/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Hey I have written few tutorial, I guess it would help you in understanding logback and how can you achieve you above task.

Check https://github.com/abdulwaheed18/Slf4jTutorial